# Custom Android View Pager Animation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-pagetransformer

I am trying to achieve this animation using the page Transformer.

[image: This is the animation]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this animation by using [StackPageTransformer library](https://github.com/fashare2015/StackPageTransformer).

[image]

[InfiniteCards library](https://github.com/BakerJQ/Android-InfiniteCards) will also be what you want.

[image]